# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in.. when i'm trying to display my errors in register.. using array display

Tags: php

I have my php code here:

```
    if(empty($_POST) === false)
{
    $required_fields = array('username','password','confirm_password','first_name','email');
        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
        {
            if(empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true)
            {
                $errors() = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
                break 1;
            }
        }
}

print_r($errors);
```

what I'm trying to do is display the arrays so that I can figure out where's my error..
but my browser said that `Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in`.. and it marks my fatal error in this statement.
`$errors() = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';`

help me please.. anyway this for registration-form.php :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the bracket to square ones:

```
$errors[] = 'Fields marked with an asterisk are required';
```